# How can I make big multidimensional variables seem shorter in PHP?

Tags: php, variables, scope

I'm creating a php class which is getting slightly out of hand the deeper it gets.

Here's an example:

```
unset($this->file[$key]->inspect->formats);
unset($this->file[$key]->inspect->tags);
unset($this->file[$key]->inspect->chapters);
unset($this->file[$key]->inspect->annotations);
unset($this->file[$key]->inspect->automatic_captions);
unset($this->file[$key]->inspect->subtitles);

$this->file[$key]->inspect->name = trim($this->file[$key]->inspect->name);
$this->file[$key]->inspect->artist = trim($this->file[$key]->inspect->artist);
```

Instead of writing `$this->file[$key]->inspect` for every single variable I want to use is there a way I can set a variable e.g `$inspect` to take this place?

So that when I write `$inspect->subtitles` it'll know what I really mean and affect the main `$this->file[$key]->inspect->subtitles`?

Comment: `$inspect = $this->file[$key]->inspect;`

Comment: @hassan "affect the main $this->file[$key]->inspect->subtitles?" if I were to do what you suggest, then run `$inspect->subtitles = 'test'` it would only affect this new object. Also it doesn't really help when trying to keep memory usage to a minimum

Comment: $inspect = &$this->file[$key]->inspect;

Comment: @MacBooc Exactly what I was after!!! Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$inspect = &$this->file[$key]->inspect;
```

declare this. Now you can set your data like this

```
$inspect->formats = 'format';
$inspect->subs = 'subs';
// ...
```

adding the `&` you will affect the variable and not only a copy of this variable

here are explanations about references http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatare.php

Answer (score 0):

One approach you could use is replicate the `object_get()` helper method from Laravel that will fetch elements based on `dot` notation.

```
/**
 * Get an item from an object using "dot" notation.
 *
 * @param  object  $object
 * @param  string  $key
 * @param  mixed   $default
 * @return mixed
 */
function object_get($object, $key, $default = null)
{
    if (is_null($key) || trim($key) == '') return $object;

    foreach (explode('.', $key) as $segment)
    {
        if ( ! is_object($object) || ! isset($object->{$segment}))
        {
            return value($default);
        }

        $object = $object->{$segment};
    }

    return $object;
}


$ob = new StdClass();

$ob->property->name->value = 'Lol';

echo object_get($ob, 'property.name.value');
```

Unfortunately there'd be a bit of extra implementation if the `$object->property` was an array like in your example.